# Doctrine Priority select depends on a field value

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Regards on this result set from this Query :

Select * from [My_Table]

```
FK_id| name   | code  |
___________________
1 | first  | 21500 |
___________________
1 | first  | 0     |
___________________
2 | second | 21500 |
___________________
4 | four   | 21500 |
___________________
4 | four   | 42000 |
___________________
4 | four   | 0     |
___________________
5 | fifth  | 0     |
___________________
5 | fifth  | 42000 |
___________________
6 | six  | 0       |
___________________
```

I need to select lines (distinct Fk_ID) where those condition are satisfied :

If code is different to `0` we take the one with the code we want(its a parameter to the query)
If there is no line equal to this parameter we take the one with `0`.

This is what I need :

If `code = 21500` :

```
Fk_id| name   | code  |
___________________
1 | first  | 21500 |
___________________
2 | second | 21500 |
___________________
4 | four   | 21500 |
___________________
5 | fifth  | 0     |
___________________
6 | six  | 0       |
___________________
```

If `code = 42000` :

```
Fk_id| name   | code  |
___________________
1 | first  | 0     |
___________________
4 | four   | 42000 |
___________________
5 | fifth  | 42000 |
___________________
6 | six  | 0       |
___________________
```

I need to have the SQL queries first, no need to have doctrine Query builder.

Comment: *distinct `Fk_ID`* How is it possible since they match to the `name` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an `id` column to ease the edition with PHPMyAdmin but it doesn't play any role here.

> If `code = 21500` :

```
SELECT * FROM `test`
WHERE (`code` = 21500 OR `code` = 0)
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `FK_id`
```

[Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c78d4/5/0).

Result:

```
| id | FK_id |   name |  code |
|----|-------|--------|-------|
|  1 |     1 |  first | 21500 |
|  3 |     2 | second | 21500 |
|  4 |     4 |   four | 21500 |
|  7 |     5 |  fifth |     0 |
|  9 |     6 |    six |     0 |
```

> If `code = 42000` :

```
SELECT *, MAX(code) FROM `test`
WHERE (`code` = 42000 OR `code` = 0)
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `FK_id`
```

[Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c78d4/6/0).

Result:

```
| id | FK_id |  name |  code | MAX(code) |
|----|-------|-------|-------|-----------|
|  2 |     1 | first |     0 |         0 |
|  5 |     4 |  four | 42000 |     42000 |
|  7 |     5 | fifth |     0 |     42000 |
|  9 |     6 |   six |     0 |         0 |
```

I use `MAX()` in order to get `42000` and not `0` on the first line of results.

In both queries you can replace `` GROUP BY `name` `` with `` GROUP BY `FK_id` ``.